# make an array display in two equal lines with flexbox

Tags: reactjs, sass

So, at the moment I'm tryng to make an array display in two equal lines at every resolution(or most of them), the code structure its just a .map inside a div that returns an extern component

```
<div className={usw(styles, ['listGamesBox'], ['d-flex', 'container'])}>
              {games.map((i) =>
                <Card category={i.category} cantLvls={i.cantLvls} imgCard={i.imgCard} key={i.id} info={showRightPanel} id={i.id} />
              )}
</div>
```

[how it should look, at least untill mobile breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ioYc.png)

I though maybe making two separate arrays including half of the original one each an mapping those.

However it gave me problems when making it responsive, I also though I might have to fill my scss with media queries to adjust the cards size and space at every breakpoint so it always looks like that in a 4/4 display instead of 5/3 or 3/3/2 but it's hard to believe that thats the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css grid to achieve this.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 120px);
  grid-row-gap: 0.5em;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}
```

```
 <div className="container">
      {games.map((_, i) => (
        <div key={i}>{i}</div>
      ))}
  </div>
```

Comment: though about it, i'd prefer to avoid grid since the whole project is done in flexbox and i'd prefer to not mix up displays, thx for the answer still

Answer (score 0):

flex css can be help, but i don't know what you want? a row of four, or only two rows.

1. a row of four

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

2. only two rows(need to adjust order)

```
.box {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```
 <div className="box">
      {games.map((_, i) => (
        <div key={i} className="item">{i}</div>
      ))}
  </div>
```

Comment: i need two rows of 4 elements each

Comment: so flex-basis: 25% could be help